# Google sheets array comma-delimiter not working in functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I was trying to do a VLOOKUP in a column and print results of a column left to the on to be searched. So I tried put them into an Array to move the search column to the front. But for some reason the comma delimiter doesn't work in Formulas.

What I tried to do:

```
=VLOOKUP("search-term"; {B:B, A:A}; FALSE)
```

This results in a formula parse error, also the B:B Range is not colored. This also results in a formula parse error:

```
{B:B , A:A}
```

I can workaround by using:

```
=VLOOKUP("search-term"; TRANSPOSE({TRANSPOSE(B:B); TRANSPOSE(A:A)}); FALSE)
```

But that gets really chaotic really fast. Is there a reason why the comma delimiter doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `,` because of your locale. You should use [`\`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) instead.

```
{B:B\A:A}
```

> Note: For countries that use commas as decimal separators (for example €1,00), commas would be replaced by backslashes (`\`) when creating arrays.